# With Twilio, is there any way to combine simulring with call screening?

Tags: twilio

I'd like to use the simulring feature with call screening. This sort of works, in that it rings all phone numbers, and whoever answers first is able to screen the call, but the simulring stops for other extensions as soon as the first phone picks up the call, even before the call screening is complete.

What I'd really like is the ability to continue ringing all phones until one phone a) picks up, and b) accepts the call after screening it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm afraid that when combining a simulring and call screening the behaviour you want is not possible. Once [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial) gets a response from one phone it will cancel the other calls.

You could write some TwiML that will restart the simulring to the remaining numbers with a new `<Dial>` if the screening isn't positive. It might be a weird user experience though.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Thanks Phil. Do you forsee any unsolvable problems with rolling my own version of this this, by initiating 10 separate calls to agents, waiting until one accepts and screens the call, and then connecting that one agent and disconnecting the other 9?

Comment: The issue I can see with that is that if more than one agent answer at the same time. One or more might find themselves accepting a call that has then already been answered by someone else. You could handle that with another message, but that's what you'd want to look out for.

Comment: OK thanks, I think I can prevent that from happening.